# find the value $AB$, for which $\log_{A} B =\log_{B} A$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are positive real numbers for which $\log_{A} B = \log_{B} A$ . If neither $A$ nor $B$ is $1$ and $A$ $\not\equiv B$, find the value of $AB$.

We can rewrite as

$A^{\log_{A} B} = B$.

$B^{\log_{B} A} = A$.

$(B^{\log_{B} A})^{A^{\log_{A} B}} =B$.

$B^{2 (\log_{B} A)} =B$.

$B^{2 (\frac{1}{2})} =B$.

I'm unable to deduce a correct solution with $\frac{1}{2}$.
I wanted to try a different approach by converting the powers to multiplication but can't figure out the base. i.e.

${\log_{A} B (\log_{?}A)} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $A^{\log_A B} = B$ and $B^{\log_B A} = A$ we can write:

$$(A^{\log_A B})^{\log_B A} = A = A^1$$

Hence $(\log_A B) (\log_B A) = 1$.

But we are given $\log_A B = \log_B A$. Hence $(\log_A B)^2 = 1$.

If $\log_A B = 1$ then $A = B$, which contradicts an assumption.

Hence $\log_A B = -1$. What does that imply for $AB$?

Answer (score 2):

To change from the base $b$ to the base $c$ in the logarithm below
$$\log_{b}a$$
we can use the following formula
$$\log_{b}a=\frac{\log_{c}a}{\log_{c}b}$$

So, to change from the base $B$ to base $A$:
$$\log_{B}A=\frac{\log_{A}A}{\log_{B}A}$$
and, since $\log_{A}A=1$, we get
$$\log_{B}A=\frac{1}{\log_{A}B}$$
and
$$\log_{B}A=\log_{A}B$$
then
$$(\log_{A}B)^{2}=1\Rightarrow\log_{A}B=\pm1$$
Therefore,
$$A=B$$
or
$$A=B^{-1}$$

Comment: Can you clarify how you derived the first equation?

Comment: @Edmund change of base

Comment: I still don't follow. Can you please try explaining one more time.

Comment: @Edmund I just edited my answer. Any questions, don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\log_A(B) = \log_B(A) \\
\frac{\ln(B)}{\ln(A)}=\frac{\ln(A)}{\ln(B)} \\
(\ln(B))^2=(\ln(A))^2 \\
\ln(B)=-\ln(A) \text{     or ...} \\
\ln(AB)=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
S0 $AB=?$